# Responsive Drop down menu with horizontal sub nav

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop down menu with horizontal sub menu. This is a project I am working on from a client and I am working from a design from a Graphic Designer.

Here is the HTML...

```
<ul id="topnav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Accommodation</a>
    <!--Subnav Starts Here-->
    <span>
        <a href="#">Subnav Link</a>
        <a href="#">Subnav Link</a>
        <a href="#">Subnav Link</a>
        <a href="#">Subnav Link</a>
        <a href="#">Subnav Link</a>
        <a href="#">Subnav Link</a>
    </span>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Hindelinis</a></li>
<li><a href="#">In House Spa</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Own A Lodge</a></li>
<li class="book-online"><a href="#">Book Online</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the css

```
.main-nav {
  background-color:#1e1e1e;
  height: 53px;
}
#topnav {
position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
#topnav li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#topnav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height:53px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height:53px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#topnav li:nth-child(3) {
   display:block;
   width:83px;
   height:53px;
   margin:15px;
   background-image:url('images/hindelinis.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   text-indent: 9999px;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
#topnav li:hover a {color:#f6f6f6;}
.book-online {
    background-color:#406340;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:30px;
}
#topnav li span {
    display: none; /*--Hide by default--*/
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:53px;
    min-width: 900px;
    height:100px;
    color: #000;
}
#topnav li:hover span { display: block; } /*--Show subnav on hover--*/
#topnav li span a { color:#000!important;display: inline; } 
.current-menu-item {display:block!important;}
```

I have put the link to the codepen so you can see what I have so far. It is here [Codepen](https://codepen.io/83creative/pen/NNzxVz)

I am running into a few issues with this style of navigation. I am hoping you guys here can help.

1. I want to push this navigation across to the right, without it affecting the sub menu below.

I also believe there is a better way to code this to give me more flexibility, particularly when trying to make it responsive.

Because of some of the width declarations in there I am finding it difficult to make it responsive without completely changing the CSS.

If anybody could help, or suggest, or guide that would be so helpful for me.

At the minute it feels too hacky for my liking and I would like it to work much cleaner and be more flexible responsively.

Any help would be great

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0):

give .main-nav class a float: right; property.

Comment: Because I was using a grid, floating right wasn't behaving properly, which is why it hadn't worked for me before. I since took the navigation out of the grid and updated it. The updated codepen is [HERE](http://codepen.io/83creative/pen/NNzxVz)

Thanks for your help Sagar Sinha.